# Jquery UI Slider - Assigning a name to values

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, names

I need to assign names to the values of a Jquery UI slider – is this possible?

Here's the code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#slider_style").slider({
            value:2,
            min: 1,
            max: 3,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#style_type").val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $("#style_type").val( $("#slider_style").slider("value") ); 
    });
</script>
```

Basically I want to make 1 appear in the `#slider_style` div as the word PLAY, 2 as the word HEAL and 3 as RELAX – can anyone point out how this is achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a lookup object to get the values:

```
var lookup = {
    1: 'PLAY',
    2: 'HEAL',
    3: 'RELAX'
}
```

And then in your `slide` function set the value from that object:

```
...
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#style_type').val(lookup[ui.value]);
}
```

That will make the `#style_type` get PLAY, HEAL or RELAX as value depending on the slider. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes!! I'm a bit of a noob though - how would I go about implementing that into my code?

Comment: I understand to amend the slide: function. But I'm usure where to add the lookup object??

Comment: Right got it working... with one flaw...

How can I get the value to appear in the #style_type as the lookup object by default?

At moment it only displays as 1 then does as I want when the slider is moved.

Code is now:-

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 var lookup = {
      1: 'PLAY',
    2: 'HEAL',
    3: 'RELAX'
}

  $("#slider_style").slider(
  {
   value:1,
   min: 1,
   max: 3,
   step: 1,
   slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#style_type').val(lookup[ui.value]);
}

  });
  $("#style_type").val( $("#slider_style").slider("value") );
  
 });
 </script>

Comment: Before `$("#slider_style").slider...` row, add `$('#style_type').val(lookup[2]);`, as you have 2 as the default value in the slider. If it helps you, don't forget to +1 and set this answer as accepted.

Comment: Cheers! I moved the $('#style_type').val(lookup[2]); to below the row $("#style_type").val( $("#slider_style").slider("value") ); and this works fine!

Comment: tried to plus one but it won't let me - I'm too new... massive thanks though.